# How to handle un-formatted text block returned from shell_exec PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I'm using `shell_exec` to interact with [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/). It's all working great but I'm at a bit of a loss as how to handle this particular issue.

Running the `sox --i file.mp3` command with `shell_exec` returns the following block of un-formatted text :

```
Input File     : '/path/to/audiofile/file.mp3'
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 44100
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:06:11.05 = 16363349 samples = 27828.8 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 5.94M
Bit Rate       : 128k
Sample Encoding: MPEG audio (layer I, II or III)
```

What would be the best approach to traversing and assigning this text to an array back in PHP? Preferably giving me something like :

```
[
    "Input File" => "/path/to/audiofile/file.mp3",  
    "Channels" => 2, 
    "Sample Rate" => 44100,
    "Precision" => "16-bit",

    etc etc..
];
```

I'm assuming it would be some form of highly customized regex but I'm at a bit of a loss as where to start.

Any suggestions?

***EDIT** This question has been marked as a duplicate and down voted as such. The 'duplicate' answer supplied does not help my situation at all, it is addressing a very specific request, as is mine. Also Mario's first reply to my question was "Yes, a very *trivial* regex.". Not only unhelpful but totally condescending. It's obvious that I'm asking for help with the regex here.

***EDIT 2**

In case anybody else is struggling with something like this I found a very dirty, not ideal way to do it as long as you know your input string is always going to contain the same set of keys.

```
$str = "Input File : '/path/to/audiofile/file.mp3' Channels : 2 Sample Rate : 44100 Precision : 16-bit Duration : 00:06:11.05 = 16363349 samples = 27828.8 CDDA sectors File Size : 5.94M Bit Rate : 128k Sample Encoding: MPEG audio (layer I, II or III)";

$array = preg_split("/[\s,]*\\\"([^\\\"]+)\\\"[\s,]*|" . "[\s,]*'([^']+)'[\s,]*|" . "[\s,]+/", $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Will spit out something like this :

```
Array
(
[0] => Input
[1] => File
[2] => :
[3] => /path/to/audiofile/file.mp3
[4] => Channels
[5] => :
[6] => 2
[7] => Sample
[8] => Rate
[9] => :
[10] => 44100
[11] => Precision
[12] => :
[13] => 16-bit
[14] => Duration
[15] => :
[16] => 00:06:11.05
[17] => =
[18] => 16363349
[19] => samples
[20] => =
[21] => 27828.8
[22] => CDDA
[23] => sectors
[24] => File
[25] => Size
[26] => :
[27] => 5.94M
[28] => Bit
[29] => Rate
[30] => :
[31] => 128k
[32] => Sample
[33] => Encoding:
[34] => MPEG
[35] => audio
[36] => (layer
[37] => I
[38] => II
[39] => or
[40] => III)
)
```

And then you can traverse each element and set a new array with it :

```
$newArray = [
    'Input File' => $array[3],
    'Channels' => $array[6],
    etc etc ...
];
```

Comment: I first thought I could do it by exploding the entire string using the colon `:` but it would mess up when it hit the Duration.

Comment: Actually after trying `explode` it messes up on the very first line.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to split everything and rebuild the format but in an array that I can traverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
"~^\h*(.*?)\h*:\h*(?|'([^']+)'|(.*))~m"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/skyZef/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of the line (as `m` modifier makes `^` match also at the start of every line)
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\h*:\h*` - a `:` enclosed with 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(?|'([^']+)'|(.*))` - a branch reset group matching 1 of the 2 alternatives:

  - `'([^']+)'` - a `'`, then Group 2 capturing any 1+ chars other than `'` and then a `'`
  - `|` - or
  - `(.*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (to the end of the line)

Note that inside the [**branch reset group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html), all capturing groups share the same IDs.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/3utKl2):

```
$re = '/^\h*(.*?)\h*:\h*(?|\'([^\']+)\'|(.*))/m';
$str = 'Input File     : \'/path/to/audiofile/file.mp3\'
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 44100
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:06:11.05 = 16363349 samples = 27828.8 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 5.94M
Bit Rate       : 128k
Sample Encoding: MPEG audio (layer I, II or III)';

if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches)) {
    print_r(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Input File] => /path/to/audiofile/file.mp3
    [Channels] => 2
    [Sample Rate] => 44100
    [Precision] => 16-bit
    [Duration] => 00:06:11.05 = 16363349 samples = 27828.8 CDDA sectors
    [File Size] => 5.94M
    [Bit Rate] => 128k
    [Sample Encoding] => MPEG audio (layer I, II or III)
)
```